# Increase a div height automatically (100% parent) leaving a top and bottom margin?

Tags: css, html, height, sticky-footer

http://jsfiddle.net/YumHS/

In the page given in the jsfiddle der is a sidebar in the cont div.

```
<section class="cont">
                <div class="sidebar">
                    <ul>
                      <li>sidebar</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                  <div class="cm_logo"><img src="img/turf_cm_logo.png"></div>
                </div>
</section>
```

The sidebar has a right border. Der is a 10px margin in the top side of the sidebar. Similarly I want 10 margin in the bottom part also. I have used 100% height so that div.sidebar fills up entire screen. But with this method margin is not available at bottom since i'm using a sticky footer. What can I do for this? Please help.

Check the jsfiddle for the demo, to understand my question

Comment: see my answer and let me know if any issues or i am lagging some where.. See DEMO fiddle for exact output.

Comment: dear see my updated fiddle and let me know if any issues you face.

Comment: see the screen shot for output that i m getting in my system.

Comment: what is your monitor resolution? i m working on 1024 X 768

Comment: see the updated fiddle as per your requirement 1280 x 800 resolution.

Comment: Updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/YumHS/11/embedded/result/  this will be final solution of you problem you can see in any resolution.

Comment: Thanks bro i m feeling glad to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the fiddle for code and demo

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YumHS/2

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YumHS/2/embedded/result/

**Updated fiddle:** 1280 x 800 Resolution as per your requirement.

http://jsfiddle.net/YumHS/5/embedded/result/

To get the desired output i use image of 1px x 2000px. and adjust the position of background image see the css below, you can set the height( see `110%;`) of background image as you want.

```
.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    width: 227px;
    /*border-right: 1px solid #949698;*/
    height: 100%;
    background: url("http://img152.imageshack.us/img152/8141/fullbar.png") no-repeat right 110%;
}
```

In my system it is looking like below image:

[image]

**Updated fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/YumHS/11/embedded/result/ -  with 2px space space in sidebar and footer.

Comment: see this demo http://jsfiddle.net/YumHS/embedded/result/. the sidebar right border is touching the footer. I want a 10px margin between footer and the sidebar border. Like top of the sidebar. Also the sidebar height need to increase depends upon the monitor size or main content size. ie: always sidebar must be 10px away from the footer.

Comment: @happy singh: thanks for the reply. but 65% height won't work all the time. depends upon the page height this varies.. I want a perfect solution to make a 10px margin between sidebar and footer. ANOTHER IMPORTENT THING I FORGOT TO MENTION IS SIDEBAR IS FIXED AT ONE POSITION...

Comment: still the vertical border line is touching the footer know. i want a 10px gap between footer and the line.

Comment: but not on my system. it is still the same. maybe your monitor resolution is higher than mine.

Comment: but this does not solve my issue. the page might be visited my various browser sizes.

Comment: Your most welcome dear. I am feeling glad to solve your issue.